# Edge, Hover, and Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, microsoft-edge

This is supposed to be a fly out menu that opens up when a user hovers.

This works perfectly fine within Chrome, I've tried this multiple ways (Using CSS `:hover`, (`mousenter`) and (`mouseleave`) the issue is - when using Edge, when hovering over my flyout menu and then clicking an item within the select box - the `mouseout` / `mouseleave` then gets triggered. (Or stop hover gets triggered) until the mouse is moved again.

This is very frustrating as obviously the mouse is still hovering the div and the div element should remained opened. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="flyoutmenu" [ngClass]="{'flyoutmenuhover': this.hoveringFlyOutMenu}" (mouseover)="this.hoveringFlyOutMenu = true;" (mouseout)="this.hoveringFlyOutMenu = false;">   
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedAccountNumber" size="20" multiple="false">
       <option *ngFor="let account of accounts" >
          {{account}}
        </option>   
    </select> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flyoutmenu {
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  margin-top:100px;
  margin-bottom:100px;
  width:40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  border-left: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;

  select {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
}

// .flyoutmenu:hover {
//   width:300px!important;
//   transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
// }

.flyoutmenuhover {
  width:300px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Partial TS:

```
public accounts = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6'];
public selectedAccountNumber = '';
public hoveringFlyOutMenu = false;
```

Comment: I've noticed, when adding `<button>` to the div, and clicking on that element - the menu behaves correctly and stays open. So this appears to be some kind of edge compatibility bug with `<select>` and the hover event on parent items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is some sort of bug with good ol' edge and there may be a workaround to get this to work correctly, but what I did in this case was removed the `<select>` and replaced it with an ngFor `<button>` then I stylized the button to look the same as the options would have.